# @State Property not accumulating

Tags: swift, xcode

Users can swipe left or right on a stack of cards to simulate "true" or "false" to a series of quiz questions. I have a @State var called userScore initialized to 0. When dragGesture .onEnded, I compare the "correctAnswer" with the "userAnswer." If they match, add 1 point to the userScore.

The problem: The console prints 1 or 0. The score does not ACCUMULATE.

Please help me calculate the user's final score? Thanks in advance. . .

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    
    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State var userScore: Int = 0
    @State var userAnswer: Bool = false
    private var currentQuestion: Question
    
    private var onRemove: (_ user: Question) -> Void
    
    init(user: Question, onRemove: @escaping (_ user: Question) -> Void) {
        self.currentQuestion = user
        self.onRemove = onRemove
    }

    var body: some View {
                
        ZStack {
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                .fill(
                    Color.black
                        .opacity(1 - Double(abs(offset.width / 50)))
                )
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                        .fill(offset.width > 0 ? Color.green : Color.red)
                        //.overlay(offset.width > 0 ? likeGraphics() : dislikeGraphics(), alignment: .topLeading)
                )
                .shadow(color: .red, radius: 5, x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            
            VStack {
                
                Image(currentQuestion.imageIcon)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                
                ScrollView {
                    Text(currentQuestion.questionText)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 375) //check: www.ios-resolution.com
        .offset(offset)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(offset.width / 400.0 ) * 15, anchor: .bottom)
        //.opacity(2 - Double(abs(offset.width / 50.0))) //fade on drag too?
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        offset = gesture.translation
                    }
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    withAnimation(.interactiveSpring()) {
                        if abs(offset.width) > 100 {
                            onRemove(currentQuestion)
                            
                            if (currentQuestion.correctAnswer == determineSwipeStatus()) {
                                userScore += 1
                            }
                            print(userScore)
                            
                        } else {
                            offset = .zero
                        }
                    }
                }
        )
    }
    
    func determineSwipeStatus() -> Bool {
        
        if(offset.width > 0) {
            userAnswer = true
        } else if (offset.width < 0) {
            userAnswer = false
        }
        
        return userAnswer
    }
    
    func getAlert() -> Alert {
        return Alert(
            title: Text("Your group is \(userScore)% cult-like!"),
            message: Text("Would you like to test another group?"),
            primaryButton: .default(Text("Yes, test another group"),
                action: {
                //transition back to screen one
                //self.showQuizPageScreen.toggle()
                }),
            secondaryButton: .cancel())
    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(user: Question(id: 1,
                                imageIcon: "icon1",
                                questionText: "Dummy placeholder text",
                                correctAnswer: true),
                 onRemove: { _ in
                    //leave blank for preview purposes
                })
        }
}
```

Comment: does CardView have a parent view?

Comment: yes, ContentView, which just holds the "quiz interface" (a header, footer, and the actual stack of cards). But the CardView is my "source of truth". . . should I edit my question to add this ContentView() ??

Comment: Perhaps not, what you can consider doing is throwing a print statement inside of CardView's initializer to see if it is being reinitialized every time the swipe finishes. If so, I believe that any information stored in CardView's properties would be lost. You may want to consider keeping the user's score in the ancestor view, and use an @Binding to read and write it

Comment: printing inside the init is a clever suggestion. it proved your hunch to be true and will be a resource to diagnose future problems - thank you. I will attempt Binding...its just, when I do, I get stuck looking for the usersSwipeStatus() and correctAnswer which are both already in the CardView(). . .*shakes fist at the sky cursing Apple*